# Laravel Mailable | ->from($this->input->mail)

Tags: email, laravel-5.6

I have created a

```
php artisan make:mail ContactFormFilledOut
```

which works nicely. But the only issue I have is that I cant access the the users mail to insert it to

`->from('users-mail')`

Im trying to get the users mail by doing this 
`$this->input->mail` 
but I get the error 
`Trying to get property 'mail' of non-object` 
so I tried also doing 
`$this->input['mail']`. 
This did not help either.

```
public function build()
    {

        return $this->view('mail.kontaktform')
            ->from($this->input->mail) // HERE IS THE ISSUE
            ->subject('Test subject');
    }
```

Here we have all the code

```
class ContactFormFilledOut extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $input;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($input)
    {
        $this->input = $input;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        return $this->view('mail.kontaktform')
            ->from($this->input->mail) // HERE IS THE ISSUE
            ->subject('Test subject');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify data which you want Laravel inject in  in your constructor, In this case you want to have access to the email address of the user who is suppose to be the sender of that email. you can do that like this

```
use App\User; 

class ContactFormFilledOut extends Mailable
{
    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Laravel will automaticaly inject the user who is authenticated and save it in the property `user` of the mailable.

You have that issue because Laravel doesn't know which object to inject when you add `$input` as parameter in the `constructor` of your mailable.

But you can overcome that is you instantiate munually the mailable and pass in the `$input` which can be any thing you want

```
$mailable = new ContactFromFilledOut($some_data);

$user = User::find(1);
Mail::to($user)
    ->send($mailable);
```